# Why does this SVG filter animation not work in Edge or Chrome?

Tags: html, google-chrome, svg, css-animations, microsoft-edge

I have created this SVG and filter animation. The box should constantly change colour.

```css
@keyframes hue {
  from {
    filter: hue-rotate(0deg);
  }

  to {
    filter: hue-rotate(-360deg);
  }
}

.hex {
    fill-opacity: 1.0;
    animation: hue 5s infinite linear;
}
```

```html
<svg id="color-fill" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100%" height="150" viewBox="0 0 300 300" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  
  <polygon class="hex" points="0,0 300,0 300,300 0,300" fill="red"></polygon>
  
</svg>
```

In Firefox 62 this works.

In Edge 17 and Chrome 69, I see a red rectangle.

Why doesn't this work in Edge and Chrome?

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=109224

Comment: But note that if your svg is only made of this one shape (i.e if you can apply the filter on the whole svg image), then Chrome at least, supports CSS filters on the root `<svg>` node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As *@Kaiido* mentioned in the comments, Chrome/Edge currently do not support CSS filters on individual SVG elements, but applying a filter to the entire SVG works on both browsers, as you can see in this example:

```css
@keyframes hue {
  from {
    filter: hue-rotate(50deg);
  }

  to {
    filter: hue-rotate(-360deg);
  }
}

.hex {
    fill-opacity: 1.0;
    animation: hue 5s infinite linear;
    filter: hue-rotate(50deg);
}
```

```html
<svg class="hex" id="color-fill" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100%" height="150" viewBox="0 0 300 300" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  
  <polygon points="0,0 300,0 300,300 0,300" fill="red"></polygon>
  
</svg>
```